# Prevent cropping occurring in cells when text wrapping is enabled and alignment is set to middle and center

Tags: microsoft-excel

The following phenomenon is occurring in Excel. Row height is automatic and does increase as I add more lines, but I always get cropped on the top and bottom lines.

[image]
If I double click the row divider on the left axis, this does not remedy the issue.

Comment: what is the bottom line, the bottom line of your data set or a table or bottom of sheet ?

Comment: Sorry, hopefully a better image now provided in the original post to highlight the issue